# Ninject ninjectKernel.Get<ISession>();

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject-2

Where can i find ninjectKernel?
I am using ninject 2.2

```
public ISession Session
{
    get { return ninjectKernel.Get<ISession>(); }
}
```

Edit:
I created a service locator to get my kernel from anywhere.

Comment: You should explain your problem more in detail. No one can answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided a code for a property (Session) of some class. This code features a get accessors that uses ninjectKernel field. Most likely you can find this field in the enclosing class.

Usually it's defined like this:

```
IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel(new Module1(), new Module2(), ...);
```

Where Module1, Module2, etc are the modules that define your bindings.